# Why SQLite3 wrap my query results in : [{"my row name":"my data"}]

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite3 for my backend , using Node.js, all is ok, but when i query the database, SQLite3 return my content wraped in:  [{" ":""}],

example: [{"my row name ":"my content"}]

Thanks, i hope you understand me question, i donk know how make the question better

```
db.serialize(function() {
db.all("SELECT  rowname FROM mytable WHERE key=" + KEYDATA , function(err, rows) {
    callback (rows);
        });
    });
```

ACTUALIZATION:

"db.serialize" is the mode of SQLite work about threads (paralel or serial mode), not about "Jasonify" data.

i find a solution, use the first element of the Json Array

```
    callback (rows[0].rowname)
```

it give the Json not wraped in "Json array"

Comment: that's json... what else would you expecte `serialize()` to spit out?

Comment: In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction., serialize is about SQLite no Json

Answer (score 1):

That's not SQLite3 doing it. It's the work of node.js. This is something called JSON. There's plenty of documentation on it here and elsewhere.

Comment: i Know JSON, the info in my database is in json format, but ¿Node.js wrap it again in Json?

Comment: Maybe. It's a bad design to store data bound to a format. How you use your database *contents* and the contents itself are not related. I'm not scolding you, I'm giving you fair warning: if you want to simplify your life, don't format your database entries to anything. Whatever engine pulls data out of there can format it to its needs.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation